# Equivalent condition for coisotropic submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, symplectic-geometry, submanifold, poisson-geometry

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold.

We say that a submanifold $N$ of $M$ is coisotropic if $(T_pN)^{\omega}\subseteq T_pN$, for any $p\in N$, where $(T_pN)^{\omega}$ is the orthogonal of $T_pN$ with respect to $\omega$.

What I am not yet able to prove is that $N$ is coisotropic if and only if for all $f,g\in C^{\infty}(M)$ such that $f$ and $g$ vanish on $N$, $\{f,g\}|_N=0$, where $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ is the Poisson bracket.

Comment: Isn't there something missing, like the restriction of $\{f,g\}$ to $N$ is zero? I'm sceptical about $\{f,g\}$ vanishing on all of $M$.

Comment: @Didier edited.

Comment: [See Proposition 7 starting at the end of page 42](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/symp_geo.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I denote by $I_N$ the ideal of functions vanishing along $N$.

The symplectic form $\omega$ gives a bundle isomorphism $$\omega^{\flat}:TM\rightarrow T^{*}M:v\mapsto\iota_{v}\omega.$$
In terms of this isomorphism, we have
$$
TN^{\omega}=(\omega^{\flat})^{-1}(TN^{0}),
$$
where $TN^{0}$ is the subbundle consisting of all covectors annihilating $TN$.
Note that $TN^{0}$ is locally generated by elements of the form $df|_{N}$, where $f\in I_N$. Hence, $TN^{\omega}$ is locally generated by vector fields of the form
$$
(\omega^{\flat})^{-1}(df)|_{N}=X_{f}|_{N}
$$
where $f\in I_N$. So we obtain
\begin{aligned}
TN^{\omega}\subset TN &\Leftrightarrow X_{f}\ \text{is tangent to}\ N\ \ \ \ \ \ \forall\  f\in I_N\\
&\Leftrightarrow dg(X_f)\in I_N\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall\ f,g\in I_N\\
&\Leftrightarrow \omega(X_f,X_g)\in I_N\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall\ f,g\in I_N\\
&\Leftrightarrow \{f,g\}\in I_N\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall\ f,g\in I_N.
\end{aligned}